# SQL Server database last_rowID

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# app with have to use SQL Server database with 1 table (`All_Data`) and 5 columns (`ID, Name, Surename, Age,Location`)

Before inserting a new row how can I find out or get the value of the last ID in the table

I have a following code but it,a not work well

```
string query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM All_Data";
SqlCommand comSelect;
comSelect = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
int ID = (int)comSelect.ExecuteScalar();
```

ERROR message:

> ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized

Please help me

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS!!** this is **NOT SAFE** in a busy system! Let SQL Server handle the numbering - use a column of type `INT IDENTITY` to get unique values!

Answer (score 4):

First, from your code it is not clear what is the value of the variable `connection`.
From the error message it seems that you don't have initialized this variable and thus you get the error.  (`connection = new SqlConnection(....);`)

However, this is not the correct way to handle this scenario.
You need to make the ID column an  IDENTITY column and then don't try to retrieve its value before executing any INSERT.
An IDENTITY column receives its value directly from the database when there is a new record to insert. And letting the database code work on this data it is the best option if you want to be safe from concurrency issues.

If you need to retrieve the ID value after an INSERT query because you need it as a Foreign Key in other tables or for your own code, then you could simply use the T-SQL command

```
 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

For example, suppose you have to insert a record in that table, and you want to know the IDENTITY value assigned to the ID column

```
 string query = @"INSERT INTO All_Data(Name,Surename,Age,Location)
                  VALUES(@name, @surname, @age, @loc);
                  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
 using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
 {
     connection.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", yourNameValue);
     .... other parameters ...

     int newID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
 }
```

As you can see, this code doesn't try to pass a value for the ID column. It pass just the other fields with a parameterized query. But at the end of the first query there is a call to SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() and this returns whatever value the database has assigned to the column ID (of course you should have set the IDENTITY property on the field).
This will work correctly in multiuser and concurrent scenario

Answer (score 1):

The error fires when the command doesn't have a connection. Please check connection is open.

Comment: it is not a problem with a connection opened or not. This is an error for a missing connection instance

Answer (score 1):

Error says`ExecuteScalar: Connectio property has not been initialized`

 double Check your connection string whether it is defined properly. You can check [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) to know how to define connection string.

you have not opened connection so open it before use :

```
comSelect = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
int ID = (int)comSelect.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
```